# Send mail to multiple friends without knowing that whom I have sent

Tags: php, email

```
    <?php
    $to = "friend1@gmail.com,friend2@gmail.com,friend3@gmail.com,friendn@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Anniversay Party";
    $txt = "You are invited for a party with classical theme";
    $headers = "From: myemail@gmail.com";

    mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
    echo "<h1>MAIL SENT</h1>";
    ?>
```

I am using this script to send mail to my friends but in that everyone knows that to whom I am inviting.

Right now all email address are shown in To field of receipt-ant of mail.

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: How about looping through the recipients and sending a single mail to each person?

Comment: What he said, or you need to add everyone as bcc (hidden recipents).

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$to = ["friend1@gmail.com", "friend2@gmail.com", "friend3@gmail.com", "friendn@gmail.com"];
$subject = "Anniversay Party";
$txt = "You are invited for a party with classical theme";
$headers = "From: myemail@gmail.com\r\n"; // I added \r\n for best practices

foreach ($to as $email)
    mail($email, $subject, $txt, $headers);
```

Comment: I will check this. Can I call this list of email address from my sql database?

Comment: Yes you can; that usually how one would to it.